# Postgresql: PREPARE TRANSACTION

Tags: php, postgresql, transactions, prepared-statement, distributed-transactions

I've two DB servers db1 and db2.

db1 has a table called `tbl_album`
db2 has a table called `tbl_user_album`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_album
(
id    PRIMARY KEY,
name  varchar(128)
...
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_user_album
(
id          PRIMARY KEY,
album_id    bigint
...
);
```

Now if a user wants to create an album what my php code needs to do is:

- Create a record in db1 and save its id(primary key)
- Create a record in db2 using it saved in first statement

Is it possible to keep these two statements in a transaction? I'm ok with a php solution too. I mean I'm fine if there is a solution that needs php code to retain db handles and commit or rollback on those handles.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend PDO (!), see my answer.

Comment: Look at: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Atomic_Commit_of_Distributed_Transactions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but do you really need it?

Think twice before you decide this really must be two separate databases.

You could just keep both connections open and ROLLBACK the first command if the second one fails.

If you'd really need prepared transactions, continue reading.

Regarding your schema - I would use sequence generators and RETURNING clause on database side, just for convenience.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_album (
  id    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name  varchar(128) UNIQUE,
  ...
);
CREATE TABLE tbl_user_album (
  id          serial PRIMARY KEY,
  album_id    bigint NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

Now you will need some external glue - distributed transaction coordinator (?) - to make this work properly.

The trick is to use [`PREPARE TRANSACTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html) instead of `COMMIT`. Then after both transactions succeed, use [`COMMIT PREPARED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commit-prepared.html).

PHP proof-of-concept is below.

**WARNING!** this code is missing the **critical** part - that is error control. Any error in `$db2` should be caught and `ROLLBACK PREPARED` should be executed on `$db1`
If you don't catch errors you will leave `$db1` with frozen transactions which is really, really bad.

```
<?php
$db1 = pg_connect( "dbname=db1" );
$db2 = pg_connect( "dbname=db2" );
$transid = uniqid();

pg_query( $db1, 'BEGIN' );
$result = pg_query( $db1, "INSERT INTO tbl_album(name) VALUES('Absolutely Free') RETURNING id" );
$row = pg_fetch_row($result);
$albumid = $row[0];
pg_query( $db1, "PREPARE TRANSACTION '$transid'" );
if ( pg_query( $db2, "INSERT INTO tbl_user_album(album_id) VALUES($albumid)" ) ) {
    pg_query( $db1, "COMMIT PREPARED '$transid'" );
}
else {
    pg_query( $db1, "ROLLBACK PREPARED '$transid'" );
}
?>
```

And again - think before you will use it. What Erwin proposes might be more sensible.

Oh and just one more note... To use this PostgreSQL feature, you need to set [`max_prepared_transactions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PREPARED-TRANSACTIONS) config variable to nonzero value.

Comment: Do we really need a PREPARED TRANSACTION here. Can `pg_query( $db1, 'ROLLBACK' );` be called when $db2 query fails

Comment: @Mayank: Yeah I'm asking same question myself. This is slightly overcomplicated. PREPARE TRANSACTION makes sense with many clients in concurrent processing in highly distributed environment (because it's only way to guarantee that trasaction can be either commited/rolledback, only way except from keeping it still open).

Comment: i guess you need there is missing a transaction block to the db2... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59058207/903998

Answer (score 3):

If you can access db2 from within db1, then you could optimize the process and actually keep it all inside a transaction. Use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html) or [SQL MED](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createforeigntable.html) for that.

If you roll back a transaction on the local server, what has been done via dblink on a remote server will **not** be rolled back. (That is one way to make changes persistent even *if* a transaction is rolled back.)

But you can execute code on the remote server that rolls back if not successful, and only execute it, if the operation in the local db has been successful first. If the remote operation fails you can roll back locally, too.

Also, use the `RETURNING` clause of [`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) to return id from a serial column.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to rollback a command that is sent by dblink

Comment: @Mayank: I added a bit about dblink to my answer.

Comment: You can do it, using: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Atomic_Commit_of_Distributed_Transactions

Answer (score 0):

### It will be easier with PDO...

The main advantage of PDO is to capture errors (by PHP error line or returning SQL error messages) of **each** single SQL statment in the transaction.
See [pdo.begintransaction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), [pdo.commit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php), [pdo.rollback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) and [pdo.error-handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Example:

```php
$dbh->beginTransaction();
/* Do SQL */
$sth1 = $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE tbl_album (..)");
$sth2 = $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE tbl_user_album(..)");
/* Commit the changes */
$dbh->commit();
```